# #APRS error ? (only visible on aprsc status)

Tags: aprs

I'm playing with Nodered that I'm trying to use to place an aprs object: it works but it does not suit me!

No error on findu.com, correct display of frames on aprs.fi or on aprsdirect.com ... but on the other hand aprsr-is server is reporting a problem to me.
(call f5rvx-10 here : http://france.aprs2.net:14501/ )

I've searched for a long time, tried different frames  but I can't find what's wrong : I only managed to get ... more errors ;)

So, what means this remark ?
[image: error on aprsc status page]

No column : in packet ... but where in it ?

```
F5RVX-10>APN100,TCPIP*,qAC,T2FRANCE:;TTN KONK *111111z4753.81N/00354.48Wrhttps://www.thethingsnetwork.org/community/concarneau/
```

(https://aprs.fi/?c=raw&call=F5RVX-10)

thanks for your help and best 73,
Philippe, f5rvx

Comment: Salut Philippe et bienvenue à ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Merci beaucoup Rob :-)